# Printing my 2D array, Visual Studio Basic

Tags: c, visual-studio, for-loop, multidimensional-array, printf

I'm quite new to programming and I have used  c# before switching to VSB C for school. I am currently trying to print my array through a loop, but i get a mess of irrelevent numbers. Any help or tips on how i can avoid this in the future would be great. My code follows as:

```
int main()
{

    int flightTimesAndLayoverTimes[2][6] =
    {
        (255, 238, 235, 138, 207),
        (80, 46, 689, 53, 0)
    };

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {


        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            printf("%c\n", flightTimesAndLayoverTimes[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First time even posting on this extraordinaire website, please ignore all the terrible formatting.

Comment: Where you initialize your array, try using `{` and `}` instead of `(` and `)`

Comment: and change from `i <= 2` to `i < 2` in the outer `for` loop

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. It is the little problems like these that convince me I'm in the wrong program..

Comment: The array should be `int flightTimesAndLayoverTimes[2][5]`

Comment: the printf() is expecting characters, but is being fed integers, often integers that are of a greater value than a char (8 bit=char has a max value of 255.  So you can expect to print garbage

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int flightTimesAndLayoverTimes[2][6] = {{255, 238, 235, 138, 207},
                                        {80, 46, 689, 53, 0}};

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        printf("%i \n", flightTimesAndLayoverTimes[i][j]);
    }
}
```